# Why is deleting the space? c++ .erase()

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, char, erase

I'm solving a kata in codewars, where you have to delete the exclamation mark '!'

But, when using `.erase()`, it deletes the space also. I'm not understanding how it deletes three '!' in a row.

This is the string that gives me problem:

`"Hi! Hello!"`

Debugging, it goes:

`"HiHello!"`

It ate the space and ends up as:

`"HiHello"`

This one works, but I don't understand when debugging it why doesn't appear more:

`"Hello World!!!"`

Goes to:

`"Hello World"`

I don't understand why it doesn't appear as `"Hello World!!"` and `"Hello World!"`

I used `.erase()` previously for splitting strings. I understood that `.erase(first,second)`, where `first` is the start of the string inclusive and `second` is the end exclusive, also `.erase()` is a member function of `std::string`.

--Bonus--
I tried using `.erase(pos,pos)` and works equally.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string removeExclamationMarks(std::string str){
    std::string remove{ "!" };
    std::cerr << str << '\n';
    size_t pos{};
    while( (pos = str.find(remove)) != std::string::npos ){
        std::cerr << pos << '\n';
        str.erase(pos, pos + remove.length());
        std::cerr << str << '\n';
    }
    std::cerr << "END\n";
    return str;
}
```

Comment: "_I understood that .erase(first,second) where first is the start of the string inclusive and second is the end exclusive_": That's wrong if you are erasing via indices instead of iterators. Read your reference for `std::string::erase` again.

Comment: The whole thing can be done in one line: `str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '!'), str.end());` . This is also more efficient - linear in the length of the string, while yours is quadratic.

Comment: @OP -- As to why using `std::remove` is more efficient, `remove` actually does not remove anything -- instead the item to remove is copied to the back of the string (actually not copied, but junked to the back of the string).   Then `remove` returns an iterator that points to the junked area.  Then the `erase` erases everything starting at that iterator.

Comment: The code in the question restarts the search at the beginning of the string after it finds a match. There’s no need to search the front of the string again; there aren’t any exclamation marks there. So restart the search at the point where the exclamation mark was removed: `pos = str.find(remove, pos)`. Also, with `char remove = ‘,’` the call to `find` will look for a single character rather than a C-style string holding a single character But that still does a lot of unnecessary shuffling, as @PaulMcKenzie points out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This call of the method `erase` is incorrect

```
str.erase(pos, pos + remove.length());
```

The second argument specifies the number of elements to be erased.

So you need to write instead

```
str.erase(pos, remove.length());
```

Pay attention to that if your compiler supports C++20 then you can write

```
std::erase( str, '!' );
```